# Java Convert double to string

Tags: string, awt, double, jlabel

Hello I am trying to convert these two double variables into a String so it can be displayed into the JLabel `AnswerLabel`

```
double GasType;
double CostOfGas;

Answer = GasType * CostOfGas;
this.AnswerLabel.setText(Answer);
```

Comment: I'm scared to ask, but what have you tried?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?  The Double class, for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
this.AnswerLabel.setText("" + Answer);
```

but this is better:

```
this.AnswerLabel.setText(String.valueOf(Answer));
```